# Grails taglib and filters don't work on run-app

Tags: grails

I'm not sure why, but when I use grails run-app to run the server (tomcat). The filters and taglib won't work. I have to use grails run-war instead.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Please check if it works with `grails prod run-app` -- it may be something with your development configuration, e.g. application URL.

Comment: It also didn't work on grails prod run-app as well.

Comment: Have you already tried 'grails clean' before run-app?

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work. :(

Comment: You can also try wiping $HOME/.grails/<version>/projects/<project> by hand.

Comment: I just found the problem, for some reason grails didn't change the file grails.xml under web-app direction for me. So, when I run grails run-app it couldn't find any filters or taglib for me.